# How can I use PHP & NodeJS for realtime notifications?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, node.js

I need to be able to get realtime notifications once a PHP script has finished, Im using jQuery, PHP, AJAX, nodeJS.

I send some stuff via AJAX to the PHP script, I need to be able to notify the user when this script starts (simple) but I need to be able to use nodeJS to notify when it’s finished.

**AJAX Script**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.rules-table').on('click', '.runRule', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    var ruleID = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/ajax/run-rule.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        ruleID: ruleID
      },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });

  });
});
```

Sends to a PHP script which does a load of processing (could take a while)
so I need to access NodeJS from here to notify the user it's running, then notify when it's finished. How can i?

Comment: websockets may help you

Comment: i don't know why you need to use nodejs as web-sockets are available in php as well and if you want to use nodejs then why have your partial project in php. you should try rethink your stack just, using nodejs just for real-time notification doesn't make much sense

Comment: @AJS Well it does, I'm a semi-decent JavaScript developer, never used web sockets and don't want to spend time learning web sockets.

Comment: Well nodejs is not websockets, it is a platform similar  to php, you will need to learn  about websockets as you will be using socket io ie. Websockets

Comment: And i mean no offense  by this just informing  you, as you may have misunderstood  what nodejs is

Comment: Check out [this](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/chat-app-with-php-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

When Ajax makes request to php at the starting store sessionid and  request id to any database like redis and Use NodeJs with Socket.io for sending real time notifications. In your PHP  code create a function like below where $data is the information and $requestId is the id of the ajax request. And in your nodeJs code get the session id regarding that requestId and emit the message to be diplayed.

```
public static function sendSocketMessage($data, $requestId) {

    $url = 'http://' . url . ':3000/publish?salt=<some_salt>';
    $curl = new \skeeks\yii2\curl\Curl();
    $curl->setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
        'id' => $requestId,
        'message' => $data,
    )));
    $curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
    return $curl->post($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go is to implement a messaging service in nodeJS. Basicaly a messaging service is a service where client can subscribe to some sort of events. Also another client can push events to the service (so this event can be delivered to subscribed client).

It's quite standard these days. Most online messaging services works that way (Pusher, Pubnub, etc) so by implementing this model in your node app, you'll be able later to outsource the realtime part to a 3rd-party service.

The delivering can be done using socket.io (which already implement a subscribing and room pattern). The publishing can be any endpoint (a socket.io special message, a REST endpoint, whatever express can handle out of the box).